# Escape double quotes in a Jenkins pipeline file's shell command

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

Below is a snippet from my Jenkins file -

```
stage('Configure replication agents') {
            environment {
                AUTHOR_NAME="XX.XX.XX.XX" 
                PUBLISHER_NAME="XX.XX.XX.XX"
                REPL_USER="USER"
                REPL_PASSWORD="PASSWORD"
                AUTHOR_PORT="4502"
                PUBLISHER_PORT="4503"
                AUTHOR="http://${AUTHOR_NAME}:${AUTHOR_PORT}"
                PUBLISHER="http://${PUBLISHER_NAME}:${PUBLISHER_PORT}"
                S_URI= "${PUBLISHER}/bin/receive?sling:authRequestLogin=1"
            }
            steps {
                sh 'curl -u XX:XX --data "status=browser&cmd=createPage&label=${PUBLISHER_NAME}&title=${PUBLISHER_NAME}&parentPath =/etc/replication/agents.author&template=/libs/cq/replication/templates/agent" ${AUTHOR}/bin/wcmcommand'
            }
```

The above command, in Jenkins console, is printed as

```
curl -u XX:XX --data status=browser&cmd=createPage&label=XXXX&title=XXX&parentPath =/etc/replication/agents.author&template=/libs/cq/replication/templates/agent http://5XXXX:4502/bin/wcmcommand
```

Note how the double quotes `""` are missing.

I need to preserve the double quotes after `--data` in this command. How do I do it?
I tried using forward slashes but that didnt work.

Cheers

Comment: You want the data to contain the `"` right? so you want to escape the `"` with a single slash on the shell, that means you need to escape that slash with another slash in groovy. Im just not sure if thats needed in the single quote, but wirth a try to use double slashes i.e. `\\"[...]\\"`.

Answer (score 46):

To expand on my comment, a quick test revealed its the case.

You need to escape twice, once the quote for the shell with a slash, and once that slash with a slash for groovy itself.

```
node() {
    sh 'echo "asdf"'
    sh 'echo \"asdf\"'
    sh 'echo \\"asdf\\"'
}
```

Result

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo asdf
asdf
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo asdf
asdf
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo "asdf"
"asdf"
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Comment: `sh 'echo \\"asdf\\"'` was the solution for me, since I could not use single quotes to wrap `\\"asdf\\"`

Comment: Thanks for providing this -- was banging my head against the wall trying to figure out who was eating my double quotes.

Comment: This works indeed, but may not be required if you just need the double quotes as part of the executed command. The problem is that the double quotes on the Jenkins Console are misleading.

Answer (score 10):

After long time of struggling and googling, this is what has worked for me on similar use case:

```
sh("ssh root@my.server.com \"su user -c \\\"mkdir ${newDirName}\\\"\"")
```

**Update:** How I think it gets interpreted

1] sh extension strips first escaping (`\"` becomes `"` and `\\` becomes `\`, first and last `"` are not part of input)

```
ssh root@my.server.com "su user -c \"mkdir ${newDirName}\""
```

2] ssh command strips second level of escaping (`\"` becomes `"`, while outer `"` also not part of input)

```
su user -c "mkdir ${newDirName}"
```

Comment: why do we need here 3 backslashes? can you explain please? I am a bit confused by this. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer, let me know if it helps.. at least a bit :-)

Comment: oh, I see, definitely helps, thanks a lot!

Comment: In the general case, this is insecure (the OP's way was actually safer): https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation

Answer (score 3):

I had double quotes inside the variable, so escaped single quotes worked for me:

```
sh "git commit -m \'${ThatMayContainDoubleQuotes}\'"
```

Comment: In the general case, this is insecure: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation

Answer (score 0):

I needed the output to be with trailing \\ so I had to do something like this

```
echo 'key1 = \\\\"__value1__\\\\"' > auto.file
```

###### File looks like

```
cat auto.file
key1 = \\"__value1__\\"
```

###### Dependent Script

```
            export value1="some-value"
            var=${value1}

            # Read in template one line at the time, and replace variables
            tmpfile=$(mktemp)
            sed -E 's/__(([^_]|_[^_])*)__/${\\1}/g' auto.file > ${tmpfile}

            while read auto
            do
              eval echo "$auto"
            done < "${tmpfile}" > autoRendered.file

            rm -f ${tmpfile}
```

###### Rendered File looks like

```
cat autoRendered.file
key1 = "some-value"
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes looking for a fix to a similar issue with quoting numbers during helm install/upgrade, you can use `--set-string` instead of `--set`

Ref: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/values/#consider-how-users-will-use-your-values

Answer (score 0):

Please note that some of the other answers that suggest using a script string in double quotes could potentially be **vulnerable to [Injection via Interpolation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation)**.

What you had in the question was actually already the recommended way to pass variables to a list more securely to a shell step.

---

What you're seeing is just an issue with the Jenkins Console, not with the script you're running. According to the [CloudBees knowledgebase](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/pipeline-single-quotes-are-lost-when-passing-a-string-to-a-sh-step):

> No action is required.
>
> The "weird" escaping is just for the build console output of the
> command that was run, which escapes things one more level than what
> was actually received (to prevent things like ANSI escape codes from
> applying to that output).

If the double quotes had not actually been part of the running script, this would have resulted in multiple commands run in the background (separated with `&`). This would have executed these (not necessarily in order):

- `curl -u XX:XX --data status=browser`
- `cmd=createPage`
- `label=${PUBLISHER_NAME}`
- `title=${PUBLISHER_NAME}`
- ...

As an example, if you run this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                echo "1&echo&echo"
                
                echo 1&echo&echo
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You get this on the Jenkins console:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo 1&echo&echo
1&echo&echo
+ echo

+ echo 1
1
+ echo

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

- The first line **with** double quotes (`echo "1&echo&echo"`) is displayed **on the console without the quotes** (`+ echo 1&echo&echo`), but is quite clearly **executed with the double quotes** (the output is `1&echo&echo`). It's just a Jenkins console display issue.
- The second line **without** double quotes (`echo 1&echo&echo`) shows what happens when the double quotes are actually missing in the script execution (and you get 3 commands on the Jenkins console):

```
+ echo

+ echo 1
1
+ echo
```

In this example, I'm using valid commands after the `&`, but in general you'll get some non-sense, which at best will not execute anything and at worst execute something you didn't want.

---

Another illustration:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                echo "asdf"
                echo \"asdf\"
                echo \\"asdf\\"
                
                # We display the script itself onto the console
                cat "$0"
                
                # We also save the test sript into a temporary file to check its content
                cat "$0" > /tmp/test.txt
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will show this on the Jenkins Console:

```
+ echo asdf
asdf
+ echo asdf
asdf
+ echo "asdf"
"asdf"
+ cat /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-project@tmp/durable-f0e4a021/script.sh

                echo "asdf"
                echo "asdf"
                echo \"asdf\"
                
                # We display the script itself onto the console
                cat "$0"
                
                # We dump the script itself to check its content later
                cat "$0" > /tmp/test.txt
                + cat /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-project@tmp/durable-f0e4a021/script.sh
```

The executed script itself (dumped into `test.txt`) will be as follows (this is what's actually executed):

```bash
                echo "asdf"
                echo "asdf"
                echo \"asdf\"

                # We display the script itself onto the console
                cat "$0"

                # We dump the script itself to check its content later
                cat "$0" > /tmp/test.txt
```