# Adding parenthesis in a string inside script of Jenkinsfile gives syntax error

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sh, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to execute `docker run` command with an argument `pass=',A-^!C}R;W)l)'`. The special characters (parenthesis in this case) throws an error.
What could be the alternate syntax for it?

```
        stage('Initiate') {
        steps {
            script {

                docker.withRegistry("docker_registry") {
                    out = sh(
                            script: " + docker run -i --rm -v --pass ',A-^!C}R;W)l)' ",
                            returnStdout: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error

```
 /home/jenkins/workspace/test@tmp/durable-5a264f4e/script.sh: 1:
 /home/jenkins/workspace/test@tmp/durable-5a264f4e/script.sh: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape double quotes in a Jenkins pipeline file's shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583357/escape-double-quotes-in-a-jenkins-pipeline-files-shell-command)

Comment: Escape characters are for double quotes but not sure how it will work for parenthesis within a string.

Comment: Escaping quotes correctly is one of the fun things about Groovy / Jenkins. [Jenkinsfile idiosynchrasies with escaping and quotes](https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4).  Consider using a slashy string.